# Async Task will not execute when class defined in library

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have defined an async task in a android studio library module named `mylibrary`. I have defined the class `getDeviceIP` as async task in `mylibrary`. I have imported that library module into the another project `testMyLibrary`. When I try to call the async method from Main Actvitiy in `testMyLibrary`, I get the error cannot resolve symbol execute().  When I put the class getDeviceIP in the same project as `testMyLibrary` it works fine. But when the method exists in the library, `getDeviceIP` is recognized but in `getDeviceip.execute()`, `execute()` method is not recognized.

THe mylibrary code is:

```
    package com.example.ramesh.mylibrary;

import android.util.Log;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class getDeviceIP {
    private String Url;
    private Integer tos;

    public getDeviceIP(String url, Integer typeOfService) {
        Url = url;
        tos = typeOfService;
    }
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //now call your ipify method which is doing the networking or calling a method that might be doing the networkign

        //getContents("http://localhost:8080");
        String ip = "";

        if (tos == 1) {

            ip = getipify(Url);
            Log.i("Service = ", "Get IP address");

        } else {
            Log.i("Service = ", "Not Defined");
            ip = ">>>>Not Defined<<<<";
        }

        Log.i("ip after getipify call ",ip);

        return ip;
    }

    private String getipify(String url) {

        String IP="";

        try (java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A")) {
            IP = s.next();
            System.out.println("My current IP address is " + IP.toString());
            //IP = s.next();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            System.out.println("======");
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("======");

        }


        Log.i("Test","IP");

        return(IP);
    }

}
```

The main Activity is

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String myUrl = "https://api.ipify.org";
        String result = "";

        try {
            result = new getDeviceIP(myUrl,1).execute().get();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Execution Excepton" + e);
        }
        Log.i("IP in main  = ", result);
    }
}
```

In the line,  , **execute()**is not recognized.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: getDeviceIP class should extends AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extend getDeviceIP class as:-

```
public class getDeviceIP extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duh! Really stupid of me.  Did not even copy the whole function into the library so it was working in another project but not in the library.  Thanks much for your quick response.